# Set core affinity for thread in zig

Tags: affinity, zig

What is the suggested way to set core affinity for thread in zig programming language? Can't find anything similar in the docs below:

- https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Top-Level-Doc-Comments
- https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#std?thread

Answer (score 1):

Setting core affinity isn't currently implemented in the standard library.

Since zig makes it very easy to bind to C functions, you can just use a `@cImport()` to load the platform-specific C headers containing the functions you would like to use, e.g. `sched.h` for `sched_setaffinity(2)`,  `pthread.h` for `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)` on Linux or `winbase.h` for `SetThreadAffinityMask`, `SetProcessAffinityMask` on Windows.

`@cImport()` will then give you back a scope that contains all these functions as if they were defined in Zig: https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.6.0/#Import-from-C-Header-File